# Internal server error, what is blocking an htaccess file allowing to index dirs

Tags: apache-2.2, 500-error, directoryindex

First time writing an .htaccess, so...

I try to allow indexing of a dir and later one adding a password for the specific dir. I herefor am writing an .htaccess file.

The server I'm working on denies indexing of dirs (I think) yet not the use of .htaccess files in itself. I make that statement for it does not return an internal error when adding the following lines in my htaccess file in the dir I would like to allow indexing for:

```
<Files index.html>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Files>
```

I do get an internal error when I use the following:

```
<Files index.html>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Files>

<Directory>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

I used the above for they are very simple statements and I am merely checking whether the .htaccess file works.

I presume that this has something to do with a deny in some config file on the server. I checked the apache2.conf and modifying that one did not seem to do much. Maybe I modified it incorrectly, however...
I also think it might have something to do with the 000-default file (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/) for their it is stated the following:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride Limit
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Which I presume must become a +Indexes. But the file 000-default is a symbolic link and I don't know where it links to and where the file can be found. Or should I not touch this one and add a new file linking to the dir...

Comment: You don't need those `[Code]` pseudo-tags in your question, If I were you I'd edit them out for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory): `<Directory>` cannot be used in an htaccess [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/directive-dict.html#Context).

What happens when you place `Options Indexes` or `DirectoryIndex index.html` in your .htaccess?

---

The use of .htaccess files in directories (and what they are allowed to contain) has to be configured in the main `apache2.conf` configuration file (or in a config file it [includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#include)) as described in the documentation for **[AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride)**

My Apache configuration file has

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

The `AllowOverride None` applies to all directories that are a subdirectory of `/`.
Later there should be this

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Which reinforces that rule for the main Document Root and all it's subdirectories.

---

The filename `.htaccess` is a default but can be changed using the [AccessFilename](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#accessfilename) directive in `apache2.conf`, so I would check that this directive is NOT present.

---

When you edit `apache2.conf` you should ask the running Apache service to reload it's configuration. One way to do this is

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

If Apache says your config is OK, ask it to load it without stopping

```
apache2ctl graceful
```

Comment: I still get (for both) a 500 internal error. Just to make sure: I have the htaccess in the dir I would like to allow indexing...

Comment: For any "500 - internal error" response there will be some informative description of the problem in the `errors_log` file (which might be configured with a different name or a vhost specific name) - Can you see what the error log says? Also, can you update your question with the **full** contents of `.htaccess` (just XXX over any sensitive data values)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, learning a lot here. The error that is logged: "[Tue Dec 14 17:29:59 2010] [alert] [client xxx] /var/www/development/.htaccess: DirectoryIndex not allowed here".Which full access of the .htaccess do you mean. For the .htaccess in the dir I would like to index, is exactly what you wrote in post before namely "DirectoryIndex index.html".

Comment: See amended answer

Comment: Thanks, for that I added in that apache2.conf the following: <Directory "/home/html/development/">
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>

The following does not work either (the dir as referred in error log):
<Directory "/var/www/development/">
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>

Yet, that does not do much, still get the error. Same error log.

Comment: That last response startled me a bit. How do I...? This is terminal right?

Comment: Is there a [AccessFilename](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#accessfilename) directive in apache2.conf? Did you get Apache to reload it's configuration?

Comment: "Is this terminal?" - when Apache sees a .htaccess containing a directive that isn't allowed, it isn't fatal/terminal for Apache - it just logs the error "DirectoryIndex not allowed here", returns a response code 500 to the client web browser and carries on.

Comment: If the Apache error message says `/var/www/development` you can be sure that is where Apache is looking when it receives your request. You can tell Apache where to look by default using the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive, but there are other directives that can set up other places to look if the URL contains specified path prefixes.